# Do I use the Past Simple or the Present Perfect whem talking about my previous jobs?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Let's say I work as a bartender, and I want to mention the fact that I worked as a cook a while ago. Do I use the Past Simple or the Present Perfect? For example:

> Person A: Do you think you could cook meat?
>
> Person B: Sure! **I** **worked** as a cook/**I have worked** as a cook.

I am aware that when we are talking about the things that are no longer true, we use the Past Simple, as in my the context above. And we use the Present Perfet when we are talking about past experiences up until now, as in my example in my sentence. Working as a cook is an experience, right? I'm confused which one to use in the context I provided and in resumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Person A: Do you think you could cook meat?

> Person B: Sure! I worked as a cook/I have worked as a cook.

I would say "I have worked as a cook".

If I added "ten years ago" or "when I worked for McDonalds" or "once" or "a while back" to the sentence then I would say "I worked as a cook".

But if it was a complete sentence (or if I added "at times in my career" or "a number of times" or "on several occasions" or "among other relevant roles") then *in this context* I'd say "I have worked as a cook" (or more likely "I've worked as a cook"), because I'm bringing up experience that is directly relevant to the present.